# What I need to create an iPhone/iPad application?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am new to iPhone/iPad applications. My boss wants to develop an application which will get data from SQL and will display in an iPhone/iPad application.

I haven't developed any such application before, but I am excited to create one.

I just want to know what all I need to get started with a simple "HELLO WORLD" app, so that I can get some idea of "how to proceed". Is there any GUI interface to create these applications? In which language will we write the code for this application? I am a PHP/ASP.NET developer. Is there any difference between iPhone and iPad applications? And so on.

Are there some good links with guide on how to proceed?

Basically, all I need to know to get started with an iPhone/iPad applications.

Comment: You need a Mac and the iPhone/iPad development toolkit - xcode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started With iPhone Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development)

Answer (score 3):

It would be good to configure the server side to spit out xml, and then use something like this to parse it:
http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-server-client-tips-techniques/